# Cannot Construct Fixed Length Vector from List

Tags: haskell

I am trying to construct a fixed length vector from a list and am not sure what kind of help to give the compiler to infer that each return of fromList increments one at the type level to the length.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Typeable
import GHC.TypeLits 

data Vec :: Nat -> * -> * where
    VNil :: Vec 0 a
    (:+) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (n + 1) a

infixr 5 :+

instance Show a => Show (Vec n a) where
    show VNil = " VNil"
    show (h :+ t) = show h ++ " : " ++ show t

deriving instance (Typeable n, Typeable a) => Typeable (Vec n a)

fromList :: [a] -> Vec n a
fromList xs = build xs
  where 
    build (x:xs) = x :+ (build xs)
    build ([]) = error "fromList: list too short"
```

```
main.hs:27:15: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘n’ with actual type ‘n + 1’
      ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fromList :: forall a (n :: Nat). [a] -> Vec n a
        at main.hs:26:1-26
    • In the expression: build xs
      In an equation for ‘fromList’:
          fromList xs
            = build xs
            where
                build (x : xs) = x :+ (build xs)
                build ([]) = error "fromList: list too short"
    • Relevant bindings include
        fromList :: [a] -> Vec n a (bound at main.hs:27:1)
   |
27 | fromList xs = build xs
   |
```

[Runnable code at repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/NotedFrozenCheckpoint)

Comment: As the compiler says, you here basically say that you can convert *any* list `[a]` to *any* `Vector n a`, so with all possible values for `n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write `fromList` so that it can provide a `Vec n a` of some unknown (at compile time) `n` instead of for any given `n`. One way to do this is to rewrite it in continuation-passing style:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

fromList :: [a] -> (forall n. Vec n a -> r) -> r
fromList (x:xs) cont = fromList xs (\v -> cont (x :+ v))
fromList [] cont = cont VNil
```

---

In your example, the compiler is complaining because `n` is a "rigid type variable"—in other words, `fromList` has an implicit `forall n` at the beginning of its type, so callers of `fromList` can *provide* `fromList` with an arbitrary `n` and expect it to work. That's not what you want, because you want `fromList` to compute the `n` from the length of the list, not receive the `n` from its caller.

So the solution is to have `fromList` provide the `n`, by calling a continuation which itself takes `n` as a `forall` type variable.

In mathematical terms, you want `n` to be *existentially quantified*—that there *exists* some `n` for which `fromList` produces a `Vec n a` from a given input—not *universally quantified*—that for *all* `n`, `fromList` will produce a `Vec n a` from a given input.

There are other ways than continuation passing to encode existential quantification in Haskell. Here's an alternative:

```
data SomeVec a = forall n. SomeVec (Vec n a)

fromList' :: [a] -> SomeVec a
fromList' (x:xs) = case (fromList' xs) of (SomeVec v) -> SomeVec (x :+ v)
fromList' [] = SomeVec VNil
```

This approach may be cleaner in some cases, but may require you to implement a bunch of instances for `SomeVec` that are already implemented for `Vec`.

(You may also notice that this isn't really a fundamentally different approach; `fromList' xs = fromList xs SomeVec`.)

For more information, a search for "existential types in Haskell" should turn up plenty of further leads.

Comment: +1, though I think you're actually missing the point of the OP's idea. It seem this was supposed to be a _partial function_, working only on lists that actually have the correct length as the (caller-chosen) result type demands.

Comment: As an example what would be a sensible argument to provide the `cont` parameter with then applying the first function you wrote?

Comment: @therewillbecode Depends on what you want to do. If you're in a REPL, you might provide `show`. If you're passing the `Vec` on to another function that depends on `n`, provide that function. The only requirement on `cont` is that it converts the value to some type that doesn't depend on `n` anymore; if you don't do that, GHC will complain that the `n` variable has escaped the scope created by `fromList`.

Comment: However, to leftaroundabout's point, this won't work for you if you're trying to pass the result of `fromList` into something that demands a specific size like `Vec 3`. Is that what you need? If so, you need a different technique. (It'd help if you had an example of how you'd like to use `fromList` in your question.)

Comment: No that isn't what I needed so don't worry. The size of the computed vector should be determined at runtime based on the length of the list (as you have done).

Comment: I now realise that `r` cannot depend on `n` and that means that you need to return SomeVec instead of a `Vec n a` since there is no way of determining `n` until run time. Is that right?

Comment: I would be interested to know what the other technique you mentioned is @user11228628

Comment: Yes, `SomeVec` is a way to "hide" the `n` from the rest of your program. But the CPS version lets you provide other ways to hide `n`, like `show`. Both versions are equally valid and powerful; it's just a question of which kind of contortions you'd prefer to jump through: implementing instances for `SomeVec` and unwrapping it everywhere, or possibly rewriting parts of your program to pass continuations.

Comment: (If you had a fixed natural you needed to match against, I don't know if that's possible with GHC's built-in type-level naturals. In that case, I'd recommend other packages like `fin` that would give you enough power to do it, but then I don't think you'd be able to use literal numbers in your types, at least without surrounding them with `fin` cruft.)

Comment: I am using the singleton-nats package and my own hand-rolled fin type at the moment so I will give that a shot.

Comment: @leftaroundabout How would one implement such a partial function with caller-chosen type?

Comment: @mxs maybe you should ask a new question rather than following up on a buried comment on an answer to a three years old question...